# Self referential structs and deferencing

Tags: c, pointers, struct

If I have the following code, how do I access the string that contains "left here" **starting from the root**? (not just using `l->data`).

I tried using `root->left->data` but ended up with a seg fault, I tried to use GDB but I'm very much a beginner in using it.

EDIT: Also is there a nicer way to initialise the structs that the pointers point to?

```
struct node
{
  char *data;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
} *root, *l, *r;

root->data = "root here";
root->left = l;
root->right = r;

l->data = "left here";  //the data I need
l->left = NULL;
l->right = NULL;

r->data = "right here";
r->left = NULL;
r->right = NULL;
```

Comment: Do you ever initialize the pointer `root`, or just start trying to initialize members of the `struct` it points at?

Comment: @aschepler or `l`, or `r` even. You need to allocate space for them.

Comment: @aschepler this is the exact code I have, I presumed when I declared root that I could initialise the members from there. Is this incorrect?

Comment: so where I've declared my struct pointers, no memory is allocated for the pointers to point to??

Comment: @CSStudent Declaring the struct pointers does not allocate memory.  What you can do is declare the nodes as not pointers `struct node{ ... } root, l, r;` and thenuse the address of operator:  `root->left = &l;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably allocate memory for those three pointers (`root`, `l`, and `r`). Right now, they are all uninitialized and so are garbage (which probably point to garbage as well):

```
struct node
{
  char *data;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
} *root, *l, *r;

root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
l    = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
r    = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

root->data = "root here";
root->left = l;
root->right = r;

l->data = "left here";
l->left = NULL;
l->right = NULL;

r->data = "right here";
r->left = NULL;
r->right = NULL;
```

Now `printf("%s", root->left->data);` should print `"left here"` and similarly for `root->left->right` and `"right here"`.

Note that you must `free` those three pointers at some point.

An alternative if you don't want to use dynamic memory management (`malloc`/`calloc` + `free`) is to allocate the three nodes on the stack instead of on the heap. You can do this by declaring `root`, `l`, and `r` to be `struct node`s instead of `struct node*`s.

```
struct node
{
  char *data;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
} root, l, r; /* <-- note that they aren't pointers */

void myFunc()
{
    root.data = "root here";
    root.left = &l; /* note the use of & to get the "address of" l */
    root.right = &r; /* same here, but for r */

    l.data = "left here";
    l.left = NULL;
    l.right = NULL;

    r.data = "right here";
    r.left = NULL;
    r.right = NULL;
}
```

Comment: @AlterMann oh wow. When I saw your edit I looked up whether or not you have to cast `malloc` and I saw on another SO question that you didn't. I guess you learn something new every day (even if you've been using a language for a while)... :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I know which declarations allocate memory and which don't? I thought the 3 pointers I made were pointing to 3 `struct node` 's that were just uninitialised.

Comment: @CSStudent The three *pointers* are uninitialized. You have no idea where they are pointing (and you certainly don't own the memory that they point to).

Comment: Right I see, which declarations in C do allocate memory and which don't?

Comment: @CSStudent in general, declaring a pointer doesn't automatically allocate any memory for it.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: well, it allocates memory for the pointer variable itself, just nothing for the pointer to point *to*.

Comment: @CSStudent: When you declared your pointers, you allocated memory for the pointer variables themselves.  However, in addition to declaring the variables, you have to initialize them to point to an *object* of type `struct node`, either through taking the address of a variable of type `struct node`, or by using `malloc` to allocate the memory for one.